# socket.io connection not heppening

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

This is first time, I am using `socket.io`.I stuck at initial stage itself.sorry it's may be simple question.

server side code :

Inside my `server.js` I written the following code.

```
var express = require('express')
    ,io=require('socket.io')
    ,http = require('http')
var app = express();
server = http.createServer(app);
io = io.listen(server,{ log: false });
```

Now I trying to make connection inside `server.js` file,like in the following way.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("This is testing");
    io.to(socket.id).emit('notification', 'for your eyes only');
});
```

client side code :

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost");
socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("connect")
});
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I open application in browser, as per my code it suppose to console `connect` statement but it's not happening.

my server is running on port no :`80`Where am I did wrong, can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to use `server = http.createServer(app);` with express

Comment: you need to require http module and set the log to some value other than false. The log will tell you where u r going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the code you pasted here? Because it works for me after adding `server.listen(...);` to the server side code which you presumably have there as well. Do you have a proxy server on port 80 or is your Node.js bound directly to it?

Comment: Is there any logs in browser console? btw, you can take a look at [official demo](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for me in express it may help you.

```
 var express        = require('express')
 , app            = express() 
 , server = require('http').Server(app)
 , io = require('socket.io')(server)

 var defaultPort = 6001 ;

 server.listen(defaultPort, function() {
      console.log('Server Started');    
 });


io.sockets.once('connection', function(socket) {   


return io.sockets.emit('new-data', {
        channel: 'stdout',
        value: "Your Data Goes Here"
    });


socket.on('disconnect', function(){

});

});
```

On Client Side

```
  <script>    

$(function() {        
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');   //if you are trying on server put server url if you are working on local then use localhost

    socket.on('new-data', function(data) {

            $('#YouDivid').html(data.value);
    });

  });


 </script>
```